# MobX, React Router v4, Route using render function not observing and re-rendering when store changes

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Using a route that needs props passed in to the components, I'm passing in a boolean that is observable from my store. When this value changes, components rendered by the route are not updated.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={()=><MyComponent isLoading={this.props.MyMobxStore.ShowMyComponentLoader} />} />
</Switch>
```

This component is Observable and injected with MyMobxStore. If I change that observable, the component "MyComponent" is not re-rendered or notified about the change.

If I call any arbitrary "setState" on my top level component, it works. or if I add a dummy element such as

```
<div idk={this.props.MyMobxStore.ShowMyComponentLoader}/>
```

that makes the current component re-render such that "MyComponent" that depends on this observable behaves as expected.

Is there an obvious solution that I'm missing? I can add one of these hacks to make it work. I could wrap my "MyComponent" in another observable and pass it down that way, But that isn't conducive with my design. Though It doesn't matter that much. This is purely academic at this point. I'd like to know why it doesn't work.

**Update**

was asked to include more code.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import {MyComponent, CoolChildComponent} from '.coomComponents';

@inject('LoaderStore')
@observer
class App extends Component {
    
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.LoaderStore.setShowLocalLoader(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.LoaderStore.setShowLocalLoader(false);
        }, 5000);
    }
    

    render() {
        return( 
            <div>
            {/* note router container and "with router" wrapper one level up. */}
              <Switch>
                  <Route render={()=>{return <MyComponent isLoading={this.props.LoaderStore.showLocalLoader}><CoolChildComponent/></MyComponent>}} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

note, I know ways to get around this. What I don't understand is why MobX doesn't realize that render is using LoaderStore.showLocalLoader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following:

```
render() {
    const showLocalLoader = this.props.LoaderStore.showLocalLoader
    return( 
        <div>
        {/* note router container and "with router" wrapper one level up. */}
          <Switch>
              <Route render={()=>{return <MyComponent isLoading={showLocalLoader}><CoolChildComponent/></MyComponent>}} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```

this will cause the correct value to be sent as prop to the Route,
there is an issue that sometimes the change in value doesn't trigger re-rendering when the observable is nested inside the return value of render.

let me know if it worked

Comment: bingo. That makes a lot of sense. I'm not sure why I didn't think of that one.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are missing an observer wrapper for MyComponent
you can use @observer if you have support for decorators else you should enable decorators as shown [here](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html),

hopes that helps, if that's the issue here is a little explanation:

when you set an observable in a mobx store you can react to a change of this observable in a few ways (i'm just listing 2 for more options see the mobx docs):

1. using autorun - [more info](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html)
2. using @observable - [more info](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html)

both this methods work on the same principles, just that in the option of observable what happens is that the render function works like autorun works

it's pretty straight forward if you have an observable inside the function it will trigger it every time the observable in the function scope changes

good luck!

Comment: MyComponent is marked Observable. But that's not the issue, If I use the observable value directly from the store in MyComponent it works as expected, but if I pass the observable value down as a prop it doesn't. I can get around the issue in 3 ways. I just don't understand if the current component is watching the use of the value, and I pass that value to a child component as a prop inside the render function. Why doesn't react/mobx trigger the update. it's clear that mobx x doesn't see that it's being used. I just don't understand why.

Comment: if you can add the code or just the way you're propagating the observable down, I could be much more helpful, and just to make sure, when you say the component is observable you mean observer?

Comment: I added more code. It is the way I'm passing it down. I just don't understand why this way doesn't work. I've fixed the issue already by using a wrapper component around <MyComponent> But I want to know why fundamentally this doesn't work.